# How do I compare a section of a string without copying?

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I have a long string that I'm iterating through, and at each iteration I compare a section of the string to a constant and store some parts of the string. In my actual code, this code runs millions of times and is the main bottleneck. I think it's due to the excessive use of `std::string::substr`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::string str("0=My,1=comma,2=separated,3=string,0=with,3=repeated,7=IDs");
    std::vector<std::string> out0;
    std::map<std::string, std::string> out;

    size_t pos = str.find(',');

    // loop over the string, collecting "key=value" pairs
    while (pos < str.size() - 1) {
        if (str.substr(pos + 1, 2) == "0=") {
            auto newPos = str.find(',', pos + 3);
            out0.push_back(str.substr(pos + 3, newPos - pos - 3);
            pos = newPos;
        } else {
            size_t eqPos = str.find('=', pos + 1);
            auto newPos = str.find(',', eqPos + 1);
            out[str.substr(pos + 1, eqPos - pos - 1)] = str.substr(eqPos + 1, newPos - eqPos - 1);
        }
    }

    // print out the data structures (this doesn't happen in my actual code)
    std::cout << "out0:";
    for (auto& entry : out0) {
        std::cout << ' ' << entry;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "out:";
    for (auto it : out) {
        std::cout << ' ' << it->first << '=' << it->second;
    }
}
```

Here are my questions:

- How can I perform comparisons on the string without performing a copy and without writing the comparison for each character, e.g. `str[pos + 1] == '0' && str[pos + 2] == '=' && ...`?
- How can I store references to substrings, instead of making copies every time I add to `out0` and `out`?

This may be a great case for the use of `char *`, but I've never used it before.

**Edit:**

Unfortunately, I've only got C++11; otherwise, `std::string_view` is the best answer. Is there a way to accomplish the storage of references without `std::string_view`?

Comment: Use `std::char_traits<char>::compare` to compare character sequences directly. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/compare . There's an example in my answer.

Comment: I was also looking for the ability to store references to segments in the string without copying, which I accomplished by just storing a `char*` and a `size_t`. Thanks for the comprehensive answer!

Comment: @Kyle You can use `std::pair` for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have C++17, you can use `string_view` thus: (untested code):

```
string_view sv{str.data() + pos, 2};
if (sv == "0=") ...
```

No copies. Or even (all in one go):

```
if (string_view{str.data() + pos, 2} == "0=") ...
```

If you don't have `string_view`, you can use `char_traits`:

```
if (std::char_traits<char>::compare(str.data() + pos, "0=", 2) == 0) ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Since people have posted std::string_view, here is the plain old C pointers version.

(Didn't test though, but it'll give you the idea)

See below:

```cpp
std::string str("0=My,1=comma,2=separated,3=string,0=with,3=repeated,7=IDs");
std::string substr("test");
.
. Inside some function
.
const char *str_p = str.c_str();        // String you want to compare with a substring
const char *substr_p = substr.c_str();  // Your substring
size_t str_len = str.length();
size_t substr_len = substr.length();
bool comparison_result = true;
for(size_t i = 0; i < str_len - substr_len; i++) {
    for(size_t j = 0; j < substr_len; j++) {
        if(*(str_p + i + j) != *(substr_p + j)) {
            comparison_result = false;
            break;
        }
        if (j == substr_len - 1) { // We can only reach here when substring is hit
            comparison_result = true;
            i = str_len - substr_len;
            break;
        }
    }
}
return comparison_result;
```

**EDIT:**

Due to @Toby Speight's suggestion in the comments (which I find very nice), I'm implementing a std::memcmp() version as well. In that case, the inner loop becomes:

```cpp
.
. Inside some function
.
const char *str_p = str.c_str();        // String you want to compare with a substring
const char *substr_p = substr.c_str();  // Your substring
size_t str_len = str.length();
size_t substr_len = substr.length();
bool comparison_result = false;
for(size_t i = 0; i < str_len - substr_len; i++) {
    if(std::memcmp(str_p + i, substr_p, substr_len) == 0) {
        comparison_result = true;
        break;
    }
}
return comparison_result;
```

**EDIT:**

We got another request, this time from @Alexander Zhang, let's implement it:

```cpp
.
. Inside some function
.
const char *str_p = str.c_str();        // String you want to compare with a substring
const char *substr_p = substr.c_str();  // Your substring
size_t str_len = str.length();
size_t substr_len = substr.length();
bool comparison_result = false;
for(size_t i = 0; i < str_len - substr_len; i++) {
    if(std::memcmp(&str_p[i], &substr_p[0], substr_len) == 0) {
        comparison_result = true;
        break;
    }
}
return comparison_result;
```

Comment: It's probably better to use `std::memcmp()` than to write your own inner loop there.

Comment: You can use subscript notation with pointers too. No need for the explicit pointer arithmetic.

Comment: No need for the `comparison_result` variable - we could simply return `true` as soon as we find a match, and `false` if the loop terminates.

Comment: The reason I added it was because of this: it is a simpler convention to use `return var;` only at the end of a function. Because, sometimes you can modify your function by adding a small check after your loop and then all of a sudden, your function does not execute your extension. But it's a bit of a personal preference, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) instead of `std::string` for the key and value of of `out`.  `std::string_view` holds a pointer to the string, and a size of the string, so it is very light weight.  This lets you extract the information you need, but without having to copy any of the characters in string and any potential memory allocations of creating those strings.

What you'll need to do is get a `string_view` from the `std::string`, and then use that `string_view` to get all of the sub strings you need.

Answer (score 2):

`std::string` has `compare()` methods that take a `const char*` substring as input.  You don't need to use `std::string::substr()` to compare substrings, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::string str("0=My,1=comma,2=separated,3=string,0=with,3=repeated,7=IDs");
    std::vector<std::string> out0;
    std::map<std::string, std::string> out;

    size_t startPos = 0, delimPos, nameStart, nameEnd, valueStart, valueEnd;

    // loop over the string, collecting "key=value" pairs
    while (startPos < str.size()){
        nameStart = startPos;
        delimPos = str.find_first_of("=,", startPos, 2);
        if (delimPos == std::string::npos) {
            nameEnd = valueStart = valueEnd = str.size();
        }
        else {
            nameEnd = delimPos;
            if (str[delimPos] == '=') {
                valueStart = nameEnd + 1;
                valueEnd = str.find(',', valueStart);
                if (valueEnd == std::string::npos) {
                    valueEnd = str.size();
                }
            }
            else {
                valueStart = valueEnd = nameEnd;
            }
        }

        // TODO: if needed, adjust name(Start|End) and value(Start|End) to
        // ignore leading/trailing whitespace around the name and value
        // substrings...

        if (str.compare(nameStart, nameEnd - nameStart, "0", 1) == 0) {
            out0.push_back(str.substr(valueStart, valueEnd - valueStart));
        } else {
            out[str.substr(nameStart, nameEnd - nameStart)] = str.substr(valueStart, valueEnd - valueStart);
        }

        startPos = valueEnd + 1;
    }

    // print out the data structures
    std::cout << "out0:";
    for (auto& entry : out0) {
        std::cout << ' ' << entry;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "out:";
    for (auto it : out) {
        std::cout << ' ' << it->first << '=' << it->second;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
out0: My with
out: 1=comma 2=separated 3=repeated 7=IDs
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/69a07J)

You could take this a step further to eliminate the use of `substr()` altogether by not storing `std::string` values in your `std::vector` and `std::map` at all, but rather store `std::pair<char*, size_t>`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

using StrView = std::pair<const char*, size_t>;

StrView makeStrView(const char *str, size_t size) {
    return std::make_pair(str, size);
}

struct compareStrView {
    bool operator()(const StrView &lhs, const StrView &rhs) const {
        if (lhs.second == rhs.second)
            return (std::char_traits<char>::compare(lhs.first, rhs.first, lhs.second) < 0);
        return (lhs.second < rhs.second);
    }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const StrView &rhs) {
    return os.write(rhs.first, rhs.second);
}

int main() {
    std::string str("0=My,1=comma,2=separated,3=string,0=with,3=repeated,7=IDs");
    std::vector<StrView> out0;
    std::map<StrView, StrView, compareStrView> out;

    size_t startPos = 0, delimPos, nameStart, nameEnd, valueStart, valueEnd;

    // loop over the string, collecting "key=value" pairs
    while (startPos < str.size()){
        nameStart = startPos;
        delimPos = str.find_first_of("=,", startPos, 2);
        if (delimPos == std::string::npos) {
            nameEnd = valueStart = valueEnd = str.size();
        }
        else {
            nameEnd = delimPos;
            if (str[delimPos] == '=') {
                valueStart = nameEnd + 1;
                valueEnd = str.find(',', valueStart);
                if (valueEnd == std::string::npos) {
                    valueEnd = str.size();
                }
            }
            else {
                valueStart = valueEnd = nameEnd;
            }
        }

        // TODO: if needed, adjust nameStart/End and valueStartEnd to
        // ignore leading/trailing whitespace around the name and value
        // substrings...

        if (str.compare(nameStart, nameEnd - nameStart, "0", 1) == 0) {
            out0.push_back(makeStrView(&str[valueStart], valueEnd - valueStart));
        } else {
            out[makeStrView(&str[nameStart], nameEnd - nameStart)] = makeStrView(&str[valueStart], valueEnd - valueStart);
        }

        startPos = valueEnd + 1;
    }

    // print out the data structures
    std::cout << "out0:";
    for (auto& entry : out0) {
        std::cout << ' ' << entry;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "out:";
    for (auto &it : out) {
        std::cout << ' ' << it.first << '=' << it.second;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
out0: My with
out: 1=comma 2=separated 3=repeated 7=IDs
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/IRrao8)

In C++17, you can use `std::string_view` instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <string_view>

int main() {
    std::string str("0=My,1=comma,2=separated,3=string,0=with,3=repeated,7=IDs");
    std::string_view sv(str);
    std::vector<std::string_view> out0;
    std::map<std::string_view, std::string_view> out;

    size_t startPos = 0, delimPos, nameStart, nameEnd, valueStart, valueEnd;

    // loop over the string, collecting "key=value" pairs
    while (startPos < sv.size()){
        nameStart = startPos;
        delimPos = sv.find_first_of("=,", startPos, 2);
        if (delimPos == std::string_view::npos) {
            nameEnd = valueStart = valueEnd = sv.size();
        }
        else {
            nameEnd = delimPos;
            if (sv[delimPos] == '=') {
                valueStart = nameEnd + 1;
                valueEnd = sv.find(',', valueStart);
                if (valueEnd == std::string_view::npos) {
                    valueEnd = sv.size();
                }
            }
            else {
                valueStart = valueEnd = nameEnd;
            }
        }

        // TODO: if needed, adjust nameStart/End and valueStartEnd to
        // ignore leading/trailing whitespace around the name and value
        // substrings...

        if (sv.compare(nameStart, nameEnd - nameStart, "0", 1) == 0) {
            out0.push_back(sv.substr(valueStart, valueEnd - valueStart));
        } else {
            out[sv.substr(nameStart, nameEnd - nameStart)] = sv.substr(valueStart, valueEnd - valueStart);
        }

        startPos = valueEnd + 1;
    }

    // print out the data structures
    std::cout << "out0:";
    for (auto& entry : out0) {
        std::cout << ' ' << entry;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "out:";
    for (auto &it : out) {
        std::cout << ' ' << it.first << '=' << it.second;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try to use Regex to split the value pair tuples.

Although haven't tested if any faster

This expression should do the trick, just get all the match (all the pairs)

> (?:(\d)+=(?:([^,]*),?))*?

https://regex101.com/r/PDZMq0/1

Comment: I think some users downvoted your answer because my question wasn't about splitting the line but about storing and searching the strings.

Comment: If I understood correctly / was clear enough, you wanted to get the key / value pairs. After matching the string with that expression you can retrieve the groups